# Django Application and Apache Server with ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-elb

I have a Django application running on two AWS EC2 instances with a load balancer. I am using Apache as a web application server.

As you can see below, if I run logistic regression on [MagicStat](https://magicstat.co) using those 8 parameters and the banking.csv file, everything runs fine after clicking the Analyze button. If I use one more parameter, i.e. 9 parameters, I end up with ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error. Even when I run the application directly inside the server using the same Apache (http://localhost), it doesn't work either. Note that I make AJAX calls in each request such as selecting the model and clicking the Analyze button.

[image]

[image]

Interestingly, that doesn't happen, i.e. it works with those 9 parameters, if I run my Django application from local Apache server (http://localhost).
.

I don't know what is happening? Any suggestions?

Note: Running 9 parameters with the banking.csv file crashes my apache server, so that's the reason why I didn't share the data file here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've finally figured it out after almost 2 weeks of frustrating work. It was an AWS ec2 issue (t3.large). After I installed new ec2 instances (t2.large), it worked. I think something was wrong with the configurations of those ec2 instances.